# React Redux initial fetch issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

Here is my reducer:

```
export default function reducer(state= [], action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.ADD_DISH_FULFILLED:
      return [...state, Object.assign({}, action.data)];

    case types.FETCH_DISHES_FULFILLED:{
      return [...state, Object.assign({}, action.data.dishes)];

    }

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Heres my actions:

```
    function requestDishes() {
        return {type: types.FETCH_DISHES_PENDING}
    };

    function receiveDishes(json) {
        return{
            type: types.FETCH_DISHES_FULFILLED,
            data: json
        }
    };

    function receiveDishesError(json) {
        return {
            type: types.FETCH_DISHES_ERROR,
            data: json
        }
    };

    export const fetchDishes = () => {
        return function(dispatch) {
            dispatch(requestDishes());
            return axios.get(restPath+'/dishes')


    .then(function(response) {
                dispatch(receiveDishes(response.data));
            })
            .catch(function(response){
                dispatch(receiveDishesError(response.data));
            })
    }
}


function requestDish() {
    return {type: types.ADD_DISH_PENDING}
};

function receiveDish(json) {
    return{
        type: types.ADD_DISH_FULFILLED,
        data: json
    }
};

function receiveDishError(json) {
    return {
        type: types.ADD_DISH_ERROR,
        data: json
    }
};
export const addDish = (dish) => {
    return function(dispatch) {
        dispatch(requestDish());
        return axios.post(restPath+'/dishes', dish)
            .then(function(response) {
                dispatch(receiveDish(response.data));
            })
            .catch(function(response){
                dispatch(receiveDishError(response.data));
            })
    }
};
```

When I am calling the addDish function everything works fine, its appended to the props just like it should as the Api is returning {"": "", "": "", "", ""}

However... When fetching all the Dishes I got a problem as I am returning

`[ "Dishes"{ 
  Obj{}, 
  Obj{} 
}]`

And in the reducer I am trying to do:

```
return [...state, Object.assign({}, action.data.dishes)];
```

But here is where it goes wrong, the props is now

```
"Dishes" [
  Object{
    Object, 
    Object
  }
]
```

but I want it to be

```
"Dishes" [
   Object, 
   Object, 
   Object
]
```

and not nested into another level.

Here's my container =

```
DishContainer.propTypes = {
  dishes: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  actions: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

function mapStateToProps(state, props) {
  return {
    dishes: state.dishes
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators(dishesActions, dispatch)
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(DishContainer);
```

Comment: `return [action.data.dishes.map(x=> Object.assign({}, x))]` when fetching all?

Comment: Hi. Tried that and it still returns dishes -> [array] -> {Object}, {Object}...@TryingToImprove

Comment: Updated posts with my PropType definition aswell if that helps.. @TryingToImprove

Comment: I don't understand the response you get from the server when fetching all dishes? Is it `{ dishes: [{}, {}] }`, and is it that data you send to reducer?